# How to make smooth function from data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

After some awesome tips from @qwerty I still have some doubts

As I said, I´d Like to make a smooth function with some other colors,
I plot the graph, there is a lot of data.
The situation is this: I have a Geiger counter, and the data file rate is made minute by minute.
So I have 30505 minutes in total.
And the smooth have to be by 60 minutes and 1440 minutes.
In the end, the same plot should have the data minute by minute, 60 by 60 and 1440 by 1440. 
I could be able to do just minute by minute using this

```
 SetDirectory["D:\\Documents and Settings\\Física\\Desktop\\Pesquisa\\Dados_Chuva"];
data = Import["geiger_2015_06_30_ita.txt", "Table"];
ListLinePlot[data]
values = data[[;; , 2]];
ticks = data /. {x_, _} :> 
   StringInsert[StringTake[#, {7, 10}] &@ToString[x], ":", 3]
f = Interpolation[values];
n = Length[data];
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[n], Rotate[#, -45 Degree] & /@ ticks}], 
   Automatic}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

I got that pic

[image]

I had an idea. Plot the data jumping 59 datas, so I would plot 1, 60, 120, 180,... for example, This is possible?

Comment: It´s data from a Geiger measure

Comment: 150630102506 17.142857
150630102606 17.142857
150630102706 19.047619
150630102806 20.00
150630102906 15.238095
150630103006 27.619048
150630103106 20.00
150630103206 16.190476
150630103306 14.285714
150630103406 18.095238
150630103506 12.380952
150630103606 19.047619
150630103706 16.190476
150630103806 24.761905
150630103906 21.904762
150630104006 21.904762
150630104106 14.285714
150630104206 18.095238
150630104306 22.857143
150630104406 9.52381

Comment: Some data from file

Comment: If you want to clarify your question, and I think it's a good idea, do it by editing your post, not by making comments.

Comment: Also, I have this question for you to address in an edit: what kind of smooth curve do you think is hidden it such ragged data?

Comment: You really need to make some changes in your question to allow anybody to help you. Share the raw data by offering a *raw* link to pastebin or similar in the question, not in the comments. Explain which smooth function do you expect, as suggested by m_goldberg. Show due diligence,  show you efforts. Clarify the question: is it about the coloring, the smoothness, or graph position?

Comment: To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I agree with you, but first I´m testing @qwerty answear and soon i´ll give some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data={{150630102506,17.1429}, 
      {150630102606,17.1429},
      {150630102706,19.0476},
      {150630102806,20.},
      {150630102906,15.2381},
      {150630103006,27.619},
      {150630103106,20.},
      {150630103206,16.1905},
      {150630103306,14.2857},
      {150630103406,18.0952},
      {150630103506,12.381},
      {150630103606,19.0476},
      {150630103706,16.1905},
      {150630103806,24.7619},
      {150630103906,21.9048},
      {150630104006,21.9048},
      {150630104106,14.2857},
      {150630104206,18.0952},
      {150630104306,22.8571},
      {150630104406,9.52381}}

values = data[[;; , 2]];
ticks = data /. {x_,_} :>
            StringInsert[StringTake[#, {7,10}]&@ToString[x], ":",3]
 f = Interpolation[values];
 n = Length[data];
 Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n}, AxesOrigin -> {0,0}, 
                       Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[n], Rotate[#, -45 Degree]&/@ ticks}],Automatic}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

cf.

```
 data2 = data /. {x_,y_} :> {DateList[{StringInsert[ToString[x], "/", 
   1 + 2 Range[5]], {"YearShort", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}}], y};

DateListPlot[data2]
```

[image]